# Finding starting and ending index of consecutive numbers in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have the array

```
A=[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7]
```

I want to find all starting and ending indices of numbers that are repeated. I expect:

2 >>> [1,9]
5 >>> [11,17]

Comment: What about `A=[1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,2,2,2,2,2,6,7,2,2,2]`? What do you want for that in case of `2`?

Comment: What's your question? Have you tried solving the problem? What did you try? It sounds like you want this problem completely solved for you without trying. Sorry if that's not the case (correct me if I'm wrong), but that's not what SO is for.

Comment: `itertools.groupby` will probably be helpful, but it's hard to tell without more info

Comment: @MrGeek : 2 is the repeated number in this array and I would expect the output corresponding to the repeated number 2 to be the corresponding starting and ending index  : [1,4],[8,12],[15,17]

Comment: @lloyd : See my trial below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should help count groups of repeating integers in a list-

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

A=[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7]
B = [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,2,2,2]

def repeatingNumbers(numList):
    i = 0

    while i < len(numList) - 1:
        n = numList[i]
        startIndex = i
        while i < len(numList) - 1 and numList[i] == numList[i + 1]:
            i = i + 1

        endIndex = i

        print("{0} >> {1}".format(n, [startIndex, endIndex]))
        i = i + 1

repeatingNumbers(B)
```

Comment: Edited the sample code to iterate through each unique number and return the respective start/end indices

Comment: In fact, for a different array of : A=
    [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,2,2,2]
the output is : 1 >> [0, 0]
2 >> [1, 22]
3 >> [10, 10]
5 >> [11, 17]
6 >> [18, 18]
7 >> [19, 19] The repeated  2 at different locations is not captured!

Comment: If that's the case, you should provide a few expected inputs and outputs to explain exactly what you are trying to do. Based on what is described in your original question, this code works, because it provides the first and last occurring index for any integer in the list. Are you trying to assess the start/end indices of GROUPS of recurring integers in a list?

Answer (score 0):

My code is as follows :

```
A=[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7]


import numpy as np
xdiff = np.diff(A) == 0

xdiff_bol= xdiff.astype(np.int)
ii = np.concatenate((np.array([0]),xdiff_bol,np.array([0])))
sta = np.array([0,1])
```

The output is as follows :

```
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

All the [0,1] block is the starting index of a repeated number while [1,0] is the ending index of a repeated number.

So, how do i identify the index position of [1,0] and [1,0] in my output array?

Answer (score 0):

```
A=[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7]
A = [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,2,2,2]


xdiff = np.diff(A) == 0
xdiff_bol= xdiff.astype(np.int)
ii = np.concatenate((np.array([0]),xdiff_bol,np.array([0])))

start_index=[]
end_index=[]

for index,number in enumerate(ii):

   if (index+1) !=(len(ii)):

        if (number==0) & (ii[index+1])==1:
        start_index.append(index)

        if (number==1) & (ii[index+1]==0):
        end_index.append(index)



Repeat = np.array(A)
Repeat = Repeat[start_index]
```

Comment: How can my code be optimised for speed ? Any better way of coding?